# How to calculate the required memory for an assembly code?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86

This is a paragraph from broken thorn operating system development series. There are 3 lines of code. It will take 512 byte to load up to second line and 514 bytes up to third line. How can we calculate this? If possible kindly give me a link where I can read it in detail. Thanks in advance.

> In Assembly Language, we can very
>   easily go beyond the 512 byte mark.
>   So,   the code could look just fine,
>   but only a part of it will be in
>   memory.  For example, coinsider this:

```
mov ax, 4ch
inc bx ; 512 byte
mov [var], bx ; 514 byte
```

> In Assembly language, execution
>   begins from the top of the file
>   downward.  However, remember that,
>   when loading files in memory, we are
>   loading sectors.   Each of these
>   sectors is 512 bytes, so it will only
>   copy 512 bytes of the  file into
>   memory.
>
> If the above code was executed, and only the first sector
>   was loaded in  memory, It will only
>   copy up to the 512 byte (The inc bx
>   instruction). So,   while the last mov
>   instruction is still on disk, It isnt
>   in memory!.
>             What will the processor do after inc bx then? It will stll
>   continue on to   the 514 byte. As this
>   was not in memory, It will execute
>   past the end of our  file! The end
>   result? A crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That example is confusing.  Those first two instructions only take a few bytes.  The author was supposing that `inc bx` fell on the 512th byte.  In general you must assemble the code to know how big it's going to be with x86, because opcodes have different lengths (from 1 about 7 bytes[*]).  You can place a label before and after your code and subtract them to know how big it is.

In other architectures (like PowerPC, for instance) every instruction is the same size, and you could just count them and multiply by 4 and be very close.

[*] I expect several replies one-upping each other with lengthy x86 prefixed instructions...

Answer (score 3):

The article is about bootloader. When you write the code for a `boot sector` (and its size is 512 bytes) you have to be careful to use at most 512 bytes (510, to be exact, because 2 last bytes are used as signature).

EDIT: those 3 instructions have 3, 1, and 3 (or 2?) bytes. He was explaining the case when this code already starts at large offset.

Usual way to compute the size of code is to take difference between two labels around a code block.

Comment: That I know. My question is about how he calculated 512 bytes and 514 byte?

Answer (score 0):

Code written in assembly language is transformed into processor instructions which are interpreted by the CPU. According to the Itel x86 specification, instructions can be of a variable length.

I'm not sure if this answer is entirely corrct, but it seams plausible that the required memory would represent the total size in bytes of all assembly instructions, as well as any data loaded by the application